# iPad photo blogging recommendation

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation

Simple question:
What is the simplest, most minimal app for both creating/managing blogs and posting photos from the built-in camera?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the simplest is, as I cannot claim to have used them all, but I can suggest using a Tumblr blog with the Tumblr iOS client (or one of the various other Tumblr compatible ones), as it's pretty straightforward at both the web and iPad client end.

Comment: Unfortunately the official tumblr client requires many taps/decisions and occasional forays to safari in order to fully manage a tumblog.

Answer (score 0):

[Posterous](http://post@posterous.com) might be the easiest solution.

They have a proper app and stuff, but afaik you can control it mostly through email. So setting up a blog requires you to email post@posterous.com with your first email. That'll get posts up online. To add more posts, you just keep emailing them there. To be fair, to manage stuff, you do need to visit the website (or use the app - never tried it myself.) But in terms of actually updating, emailing photos and text is something that the iPad and iPhone do very well.